# How to pass $(DB) parameter to SqlCommand?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have the following query:

```
use [$(DB)]
select * from users
```

but I cannot pass the parameter trough SqlCommand. It works only from the command line tool. It says that $DB database does not exist, so the parameter is not passed.

```
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("DB", "theDatabase");
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not specify the DB in your connection string?

Comment: These are migration scripts which are hundreds of hundreds. MSSQLSERVER 2005 and 2008

Comment: mynkow if these are migration scripts the you should be able to determine what DB each script is working off of.. also what ever script or batch process that is doing it now.. as a temporary work around .. could you now create a console app that spawns or Creates that Process which calls the code at hand use [$DB] select * from users..?

Comment: At the moment all scripts are executed from very old application which uses sql command line tool. We are trying to refactor that application. Yes, I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLCMD has its own commands, which it parses separately from SQL/T-SQL statements. These commands are not understood by SQL Server or other scripting tools like SSMS

http://sqlblog.com/blogs/michael_coles/archive/2010/01/10/parent-child-build-scripts-with-sqlcmd.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of doing that is ti use exec to like this:

```
exec ('use ['+ @db + ']; SELECT * FROM someTable');
```

I'm not sure if this will help you but...